# c# How to revert Y Axis with Live Charts

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, data-visualization, livecharts

[liveCharts wpf C#]
I am not good at English . Can you help me with this question?
I'm trying to simply revert the Y Axis so this graph it goes down  instead of up .

```
   public partial class Window5 : Window
{
    public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
    public string[] Labels { get; set; }
    public Func<double, string> YFormatter { get; set; }
    public Window5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection { };
        SeriesCollection.Add(
             new VerticalLineSeries
             {
                 Title = "HK1",
                 Values = new ChartValues<double> { 5, 6, 9, 4, 5, 2 },
                 PointGeometry = null,
                 Fill = Brushes.Transparent
             }
         );

        SeriesCollection.Add(
             new VerticalLineSeries
             {
                 Title = "HK2",
                 Values = new ChartValues<double> { 3, 5 },
                 PointGeometry = null,
                 Fill = Brushes.Transparent
             }
         );
        Labels = new[] { "0", "-1.5", "-2.7", "-3.0", "-4.9", "-5.0" };
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

XAML

```
    <Grid>
    <lvc:CartesianChart  x:Name="diagram"
                         Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}">
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:Axis Labels="{Binding Labels}"
                      Position="LeftBottom" 
                      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            </lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis MinValue="0"
                      Position="RightTop" />
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.DataTooltip>
            <lvc:DefaultTooltip SelectionMode="SharedYValues" />
        </lvc:CartesianChart.DataTooltip>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>
</Grid>
```

Image
[Reverse Axis Live chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLXiQ.png)

Code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-NOzBjLq2qELfKzqvLDN4LBzEFpVPpwD/view?usp=sharing

Thanks everyone!!!

Comment: That's a third party add-on and I doubt many would know about it to be able to help you.
But a wild guess, since you want the axes to start from a common point then you have to set a common origin for both. i.e. (Position="LeftTop") for both axes. Or play around that to get your desired result.

Comment: have you tried to reverse the order of the labels in the array?

Comment: @Nguyễn Văn Huy - Check the following post: [c# How to invert Y Axis with Live Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998994/c-sharp-how-to-invert-y-axis-with-live-charts)

Comment: @Osama thanks you! I tried your way the Axis position changes but the direction of the Axis doesn't change.

Comment: @Gusman Thanks you! 
I can reverse the lable with the following code: Labels = new[] { "-5.0", "-4.9", "-3.0", "-2.7", "-1.5", "0"   };
but the serial value does not change!

If you are free, see the code at google drive:   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-NOzBjLq2qELfKzqvLDN4LBzEFpVPpwD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Reversing the labels won't do you any good cuz they are just stations on your axis.
What you may need to do is to reverse the "ChartValues<double>{  ,  , .. }" list
but you have to pay attention to how can this affect your data across the code.

Comment: @BionicCode 
According to your way, the number of serials is the same. But in my case the quantity is different.

Comment: @Osama Thanks you! 
The number of serials  is different so I don't know how......

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. _"Reverse"_ is just wrpng in this context. My answer was nonsense. You just want to adjust the origin. This is done automatically. You are only configuring your chart wrong based on your own misunderstanding. You currently plotting positive values on a positive axis. Only the labels are _named_ with negative values.  This means the underlying value of y-axis label -5 is still y = 5. You need to invert your series. Y-axis labels  will be automatically assigned according to the value range: multiply each value by `-1` and remove the `Labels` property.